# Animating Xaml Grid.ColumnDefinitions using XAML Behaviors when Binding Changes

Tags: xaml, animation, data-binding, uwp

I have a grid showing data received from a web service as below:
[image]

The graph bars are achieved using data binding, with the converter returning a GridLength Star value:

```
  <Grid Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding home.possessionPercentage, Converter={StaticResource statswidthConverter}}"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding away.possessionPercentage, Converter={StaticResource statswidthConverter}}"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbl1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding home.possessionPercentage}"/>
                        <Rectangle Fill="#FF1DEE00" Stroke="White" Grid.Column="1" StrokeThickness="0"/>
                        <Rectangle Fill="White" Stroke="White" Grid.Column="2" StrokeThickness="0"/>
                        <Rectangle Fill="#FF139D00" Stroke="White" Grid.Column="3" StrokeThickness="0"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbr1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding away.possessionPercentage}" Grid.Column="4"/>
                    </Grid>
```

What I would like to achieve is for the column sizes to be animated to the new value when the binding value is updated rather than just a jump to the new size.  I believe this can be achieved with the Microsoft.Behaviors library - https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/ but am unsure where to start.  Any advice please?

Answer (score 1):

To meet your requirements, firstly you need an animation to animate the `Width` property. I wrote a simple demo which use [`DoubleAnimation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br243136) to animate the `Width` of the `Rectangle`. For the reason I set the target of storyboard to `Rectangle` is that [`ColumnDefinition.Width`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.columndefinition.width.aspx) property is [`GridLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.gridlength.aspx) type that we cannot use `DoubleAnimation`.

Secondly, we need a trigger to trigger the animation.  Here I use [`DataTriggerBehavior`](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki/DataTriggerBehavior) in [XamlBehaviors](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors) SDK. Once the data greater than one value the trigger can be triggered.Completed demo as follows.

```
 <Page
    ...
    xmlns:Interactions="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:Media="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Media">
    <Page.Resources>
        <local:statswidthConverter x:Name="statswidthConverter" />
        <Storyboard x:Name="Increase">
            <DoubleAnimation
                Duration="0:0:5"
                EnableDependentAnimation="true"
                Storyboard.TargetName="rec1"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                To="{Binding homePercentage, Converter={StaticResource statswidthConverter}}" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="decrease">
            <DoubleAnimation
                Duration="0:0:5"
                EnableDependentAnimation="true"
                Storyboard.TargetName="rec2"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                To="{Binding awayPercentage, Converter={StaticResource statswidthConverter}}" />
        </Storyboard>           
    </Page.Resources>
    <StackPanel
        Padding="50"
        Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
        Loaded="Grid_Loaded">
        <Grid
            Grid.Row="1"
            Height="50"
            BorderThickness="0,0,0,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="clo1" Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="tbl1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Text="{Binding homePercentage}"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            <Rectangle
                x:Name="rec1"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Width="0"
                Fill="#FF1DEE00"
                Stroke="White"
                StrokeThickness="0">
                <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior
                        Binding="{Binding homePercentage}"
                        ComparisonCondition="GreaterThan"
                        Value="0">
                        <Media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Increase}" />
                    </Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior>
                </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle
                Grid.Column="2"
                Fill="White"
                Stroke="White"
                StrokeThickness="0" />
            <Rectangle
                x:Name="rec2"
                Grid.Column="3"
                Width="200"
                Fill="#FF139D00"
                Stroke="White"
                StrokeThickness="0" >
                <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior
                        Binding="{Binding awayPercentage}"
                        ComparisonCondition="LessThan"
                        Value="200">
                        <Media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource decrease}" />
                    </Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior>
                </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Rectangle>
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="tbr1"
                Grid.Column="4"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Text="{Binding awayPercentage}"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Code behind

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
 {
     ObservableCollection<Percentage> percentages;
     public MainPage()
     {
         this.InitializeComponent();
         percentages = new ObservableCollection<Percentage>()
         {
             new Percentage {homePercentage=63,awayPercentage=37 }
         };
         this.DataContext = percentages[0];
     } 
 }

 public class Percentage
 {
     public double homePercentage { get; set; }
     public double awayPercentage { get; set; }
 }
 public class statswidthConverter : IValueConverter
 {
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
     {
         return (double)value * 2;
     }

     public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
     {
         return (double)value / 2;
     }
 }
```

If you still want to set animation for `ColumnDefinition.Width` please use [`ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.objectanimationusingkeyframes.aspx) which don't have so smoothly effects as `DoubleAnimation` the demo showed. To be smoothly need quite a lot frames. For example:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="storyobejct">
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
        Duration="0:0:3"
        Storyboard.TargetName="clo1"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="50" />
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="60" />
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.0" Value="100" />
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="126" />
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Using which animation and which trigger depend on your layout and requirements. Pay attention that animating the `Width` seems to be a dependent animation which is not recommended. More details animation please reference [Animations overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/animations-overview), more details about XAML behavior please reference [this document](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki).

Comment: Do not animate the `Width` as it's going to run on the UI thread that could impact your overall UI performance. You should consider animating the `ScaleX` in this case instead.